# Schedule a Powershell script in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, powershell, scheduled-tasks, task-scheduler

How can I schedule a Powershell script to run every day at 3am in Windows 8?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you attempt to use Task Scheduler? Use `powershell /?` to know how to run a PS1 script from the command-line.

Comment: I tried using Task Scheduler to run the script, but when I try to test it by running it from the Scheduler, its status changes to Running and never finishes. Note that I tested the script and it successfully runs and exits if you right click it run it with Powershell.

Comment: You should have mentioned this in the original question, else as you can see below people will just waste their time teaching you how to create a scheduled task. Did you try setting the task to run as admin/with highest privileges?

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well. It is set to run with highest privileges.

Comment: Did you try on another Win8 PC, if you have access to one? I think it might be difficult to diagnose this issue unless the script contents are known. What are you trying to do with PS?

Comment: I don't have access to another PC. The script just copies a file via `Copy-Item`. I guess what I'm really asking is: what should I point Task Scheduler to? The Script? Powershell -file Path\To\Script? Something else?

Comment: How about to powershell.exe, and specify the script as a parameter? That's what I was referring to when I mentioned `powershell /?` above.

Comment: Yep. Specifically, I set the program to `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe` and the arguments to `-File C:\Users\Username\Desktop\backupapp\backup.ps1`.

Comment: I noticed after a reboot that when I try to run it by right-clicking on it, Powershell is now asking me to confirm that I want to change the execution policy. I suppose it's possible that the script is blocking (waiting for input) in the background when the scheduler runs. If that's the case, I need some way to make it not ask for confirmation of the execution policy change at start.

Comment: Also, I'll add that the command works from the command line just fine.

Comment: At the PS prompt, type this command: `set-executionpolicy remotesigned` Now you can run local unsigned scripts.

Comment: Right. I had done that before-- otherwise it would be Restricted by default and not allow any scripts to run from the command line or anywhere. I am saying it asked for the confirmation to switch to RemoteSigned again after a reboot.

Comment: Weird. Ok, how about scheduling a batch file that sets the execution policy, then runs the script?

Comment: Hmm.. I may be misunderstanding how Task Scheduler works. I enabled task history and it is successfully completing the task and the file is copied. However, it never changes from the "Running" to "Ready" state. Am I just expecting something that won't happen if I force-run rather than letting a trigger happen?

Comment: Why not set a trigger a few mins. from now and simply test?

Comment: Looks like it works fine if I use a trigger. Thanks Karan!

Comment: If you want pure PowerShell3 solution I recommend reading [Scheduled Jobs CMDlets](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849778.aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT: This is a proof of concept that worked for me.**

1. open a new textfile and type in
   `write-Host 'Hello World'`
   `$x = $host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown")`
2. save it as `hello.ps1` on your desktop
3. open the 32-bit version of powershell.exe with elevated rights
   (right click + open as administrator)
   `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
4. make sure, that you didn't use the x64 version until you want to
   `C:\Windows\syswow64\Windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
5. On my Windows 7 the "Windows PowerShell (x86)" startmenu shortcut [points to the x64](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYHjq.jpg) version!  These versions use [seperate policy settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23fB0.jpg).  It took me a while to figure that out :)
6. Type in the following to allow powershell scripts and confirm it with <kbd>Y</kbd>
   `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted`
7. That setting is stored permanently. Do a reboot just to check that.
8. check the powershell policy and confirm that it is still unrestricted with
   `get-ExecutionPolicy`
9. open schedule task window
10. make a scheduled task which points at the x86 version
    `C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
11. Type in the following for the optional parameter:
    `c:\users\YOURUSERNAME\desktop\hello.ps1`
12. Execute your task manually through a right-click in your schedule task window
13. Wonder why it says "running"
14. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh. You will notice that the  "still running"-status disappears.
15. [Be happy (after 1 hour :p)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mk0ej.jpg)

Comment: That does not work. Please see my comment in the original post.

Comment: What was the exact syntax you used in your task scheduler?

Comment: I tried it the way you suggested in your edit. It still just changes the status to Running and never finishes.

Comment: Please see my full edit. There has to be a normal way.

Comment: Regarding step 6, it should probably say "confirm it with `Y`" (instead of `J`). I realise it's `J` for you because your Windows display language is set to German, but SU normally assumes English localisation, unless specified otherwise.

Comment: Step 14 was very helpful to me, I think a lot of people have issues about their tasks never finishing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

run 'taskschd.msc', navigate to Powershell and create the job/schedule.

[Reference](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/09/18/create-a-powershell-scheduled-job.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to get my Scheduled PowerShell task to work.

Here are a few tactics that helped me.

a) Get a simple PowerShell script working.
b) Understand all the various Task Manager tabs, including the conditions and actions (I think you have done this already)
c) Watch the path to the various files.

---

My killer problem was not realising PowerShell was the program and the script was merely an argument.

Another minor help was introducing -ExecutionPolicy Bypass before the file name thus:
-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "D:\PShell\Process Task.ps1"

Finally, I am never sure about the SuperUser etiquette, but this is my page on the subject of [Scheduling PowerShell](http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/powershell/powershell3-schedule-task.htm).